# How to join an identifier table onto an array field in BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, join, google-bigquery

Tbl1

| id | eez |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8438 |
|  | 8493 |

Tbl2

| eez_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 8438 | Greenlandic Exclusive Economic Zone |
| 8493 | Canadian Exclusive Economic Zone |

Desired output

| id | eez | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8438 | Greenlandic Exclusive Economic Zone |
|  | 8493 | Canadian Exclusive Economic Zone |

So far I've done the below, but it is giving me undesired results. Any thoughts here?

```
select a.*, b.name
from tbl1 as a
left join tbl2 as b
on b.eez_id in unnest(a.eez);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id, 
  array(
    select as struct eez_id as eez, name
    from t1.eez eez_id
    join tbl2 
    using(eez_id)
  ) eezs
from tbl1 t1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]